# Is it possible to create a third party version of another website with a login page?

Tags: php, html, css, sql, web

We have a school website where you are able to log in and see your schedule, assignments etc. Is it possible to create my own version of our school website where you can log in and get access to schedule, assignments etc? My goal is to create a simplified and cleaner look for it. What kind of code do i need to log in to the school website through my own website and retrieve the information in variables?

Comment: Not unless you gain access to the website's backend. You could ask them to login at your page and parse all the data that you recieve though, and then format it as you want.

Comment: Talk to your IT department as they might be using a management system that allows portals. Another option is to check whether or not you area can be customised to only show the info that you require.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way you create a web where you can get all data you want is to have access to the original web database whatever format used: SQLm MySQL, Oracle, Access, etc. That means you need dbName, username and password. So No. Unless you are a very good hacker.

Comment: Thanks! That answers my question